# Verifying a function space to be a Hilbert space

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces, complete-spaces

Let $\omega(t)$ be a non-negative real Lebesgue-integrable function.
$$H=\{f,\ \textrm{Lebesgue-measurable}: \int_{\mathbb{R}}|f(t)|^2\omega(t)dt<\infty\}$$
Prove that $H$ is a Hilbert space under the inner product
$$\left<f,g\right>=\int_\mathbb{R}f(t)\overline{g(t)}\omega(t)dt, \forall f,g\in H$$

---

I can figure out that this inner product is well-defined and $H$ is a linear space. However, I don't know how to get the completeness of $H$. Any help would be appreciated! Thanks!

---

Updates:
To check the completeness, I need to verify that every Cauchy sequence is convergent. First I get the induced norm of inner product:
$$\|f\|=\sqrt{\int_\mathbb{R}|f(t)|^2\omega(t)dt}$$
Then I need to prove:

If $\{f_n\}\subset H$ satisfies $\forall \varepsilon>0$, $\exists N>0$, when $m>N$,
$$\|f_{m}-f_{m+p}\|<\varepsilon,(\forall p>0)$$
then there exists $f\in H$ such that $\|f_n-f\|\to 0(n\to \infty)$.

Here is where I am stuck.

---

Updates: I find this norm is similar to the norm on $L^2$, just multiplied a weight $\omega(t)$ at each $t$. so I guess
$$\left<f,g\right>=\int_\mathbb{R}\left(f(t)\sqrt{\omega(t)}\right)\left(\overline{g(t)}\sqrt{\omega(t)}\right)dt=\left<f\sqrt{\omega},g\sqrt{\omega}\right>_{L^2}$$
would work. Then use the completeness of $L^2$.

Comment: Recall the definition of a complete metric space: every Cauchy sequence converges to a limit in the space. What do you have to check in this case?

Comment: If $\omega$ can vanish on a set of positive measure, your norm isn't a norm.

Comment: @PhoemueX Yeah, indeed. I would assume that $\omega$ is positive almost everywhere.

Comment: Also note that as usual you need to quotient by the subspace of functions of norm zero or else you don't have positive-definiteness.

Comment: Another generally useful trick is that completeness is equivalent to the statement that every absolutely convergent series converges. This perspective sometimes makes it easier to see how limit theorems can apply.

Comment: @PhoemueX On the space of measurable *functions* this is never a norm, and if you quotient out functions of semi-norm $0$, as mentioned by Qiaochu, then it does not matter if $\omega$ vanishes on a set of positive measure or not.